# solve second order ODE in MATLAB/SIMULINK

Tags: matlab, simulink, equation, ode, differential-equations

I don't know how to solve this second order ODE in SIMULINK:

[image]

I rewrote it to the system of first order ODEs:

[image]

then

[image]

giving

[image]

My SIMULINK blocks are here:

[image: SIMULINK blocks]

giving this Scope:

[image]

This is the plot of symbolic solution from `dsolve`:

[image]

It looks like the functions (plots) from symbolic and SIMULINK are little similar.

Comment: In Simulink you are plotting y_dot, while the symbolic solution is a plot of y.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Of course! That was the mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found by **Phil Goddard**. His answer in comments:

> In Simulink you are plotting y_dot, while the symbolic solution is a plot of y.

So the problem was that Scope was plotting the `y'`. The correct position of Scope is here:

[image]

giving the correct plot of `y`:

[image]

as you can see in the plot of symbolic solution:

[image]