# How to solve an ODE equation in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, scope, filtering, simulink, ode

I'm studying a report about roll angle estimation. In the article I found the following scheme:

[image: this]

where vx is the longitudinal vehicle velocity, psi_dot is the horizontal yaw rate, lambda_dot is the roll rate and lambda is the roll angle. I need to verify this method on matlab/simulink

Here is my simulation:

[image: here]

I chose random values (reasonable, I hope) for vx and yaw rate, while lambda_dot is similar to the one used in the article. The MATLAB function block contains this code:

```
function lambda = fcn(vx, yaw_r)

  g = 9.81;

  lambda0 = -(vx*yaw_r)/g;

  tspan = [0 40];

  [t,lambda_var] = ode45(@(t,lambda_var) tan(0.9*lambda_var)*cos(lambda_var), tspan, lambda0);


  t0 = 0:0.01:40; 
  lambda1 = zeros(1,4001);
  lambda1 = interp1(t,lambda_var,t0);
  lambda = [t0' lambda1'];
```

I used the equations I found in the paper in the lambda0 expression and in the [t,lambda_var] one. The "lambda_d" block contains a two-column vector, the first one with time values and the second one with the corresponding lambda_dot values. Also lambda (output of fcn block) should be defined in the same way, as you can see in the code above.

I thought the problem was the scope: if I run this simulation, I do not have a single signal plotted on the scope. Instead, I get as many signals as the size of the vector which contains something like 4000 values (0.01 seconds of sampling time on 40 seconds tot).

But I understand now that the problem is the ODE equation in the Simulink block. I need to write it in that block, because the two inputs will be variable in the next step. The equation I need to solve is:

```
tan(0.9*lambda)*cos(lambda) = -vx*yawrate /g
```

EDIT: I changed the main question according to your comments.

Comment: So your MATLAB function block is wrong.  It should calculate one value for lambda at each time point.  It looks like you've copied it from somewhere where all the lambda are calculated for all time points at once, which is not what you want in Simulink.

Comment: I did not copied the code, I need to solve the differential equation  tan(0.9*lambda)*cos(lambda) = -(vx*yaw_r)/g  and that's the only way I know to do it. I'm quite sure that block is wrong somehow, because the lower part seems to work properly, but I still don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Given that Vx and yaw rate are constant, why aren't you calculating `lambda` outside of Simulink (before running the simulation) and feeding it into the model in the same way as `lambda_d`?  If in the future they will not be constant, you need to figure out how to calculate `lambda` so that you can feed it into the rest of the model one time step at a time.

Comment: Exactly, the constant blocks are temporary, that's why I want to use them instead of feeding an external function with those values. But you gave me a good hint and maybe I have an idea to solve it, so thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the integral form of the ODE, if solving `x'=f(t,x,u)`, `x(0)=x0`, you solve it as `x(t)=x0+integral( f(s, x(s), u(s)), s=0..t)`, see http://kispow.com/solving-an-ordinary-differential-equationode-in-simulink-matlab or similar sites for the keywords "simulink ode"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30149595/3088138, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574785/3088138 where ODE are solved in Simulink and compared to the exact solution.

Comment: What exactly is "differential" in the equation you now posted? It is  a non-linear equation for `lambda`, but no derivative is present.